# Magento hangs when I click Save and Continue Edit

Tags: javascript, magento-2.1

Windows 10, Magento 2.1, XAMPP,

Stores > attributes > product > add new attribute > properties

fill in [Default Label] and click — Save and Continue Edit. It says please wait... and the software hangs.

Same hang in both Firefox and Chrome.

Nothing needs to be reindexed.

My guess is maybe a file is missing.

I am new to Magento, can someone help me? Thanks.

It is now my understanding that Magento 2.1 doesn't work 100% on Windows. It must be installed on Linux using LAMP to work properly.

Does anyone else have this understanding?

Comment: I read this on another site:
"Forever turning wheel" is a clear indication of an asynchronous processing failure.

My guess is the database is missing something or maybe a file is missing.